# avast blocks joomla web-site because of "JS:HideMe-H"

Tags: windows, joomla

I am new boy to joomla. I have created a web site using joomla its works good in linux o.s and others. The website blocked appears on windows with avast.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an element in your code with `id=hideMe`. This is generated by an ad or something embedded there. If you are sure about your website then this is a false positive. Otherwise find and remove the code that generates this snippet. You can find more info on this [here](http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=131579.0) or [here](http://www.joomlage.com/forum/5-commercial-joomla-templates-support/3473-avast-detects-a-trojan).